# Extract letter from equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with extracting R from equation. I know all values except for R.
Thank you for help.

$U_d = U_o *(1-e^{-\frac{t_c}{RC}})$

Answer (score 0):

$U_d = U_o \cdot (1-e^{-\frac{t_c}{RC}})$

$\frac{U_d}{U_o} = 1-e^{-\frac{t_c}{RC}}$

$1-\frac{U_d}{U_o} = e^{-\frac{t_c}{RC}}$

$ln(1-\frac{U_d}{U_o}) = -\frac{t_c}{RC}$

$R\cdot ln(1-\frac{U_d}{U_o}) = \frac{-t_c}{C}$

$R = \frac{-t_c}{C \cdot ln(1-\frac{U_d}{U_o})} $